# Create input component and control multiple form states in React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My project has 2 separated forms, 'user' and 'movies'. I have created a single input component which I want to use in all 3 forms. This isn't the complex thing to do but I am wondering what the right approach is to save the data on every keystroke or blur action to the right redux store state.

So I have 2 reducers and 2 forms, 'user' and 'movies'. The user form contains just some user and user meta data. The movies form will be a 'collection' of movies the user has seen.

I have created this text field component

```
import React from 'react';

class TextField extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      name: this.props.name,
      value: this.props.value
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    const {
      value
    } = e.target

    this.setState({
      value: value
    });
  }

  onBlur = (e) => {
    const {
      value
    } = e.target

    this.setState({
      value: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <input
        type="text"
        name={this.state.name}
        value={this.state.value}
        onBlur={(e) => this.onBlur(e)}
        onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default TextField;
```

And in the form component

```
<TextField
   name={`${this.state.movies}[${index}].name`}
   value={item.name}
/>
```

No, I need the right approach to write the values by onChange or onBlur directly to the right 'user' or 'movies' sate. e.g. movies[1].name should be append to the movies state via reducer:

```
movies : [{
  name: 'movie #1'
 },
  name: 'movie #2'
}]
```

Should I pass down on every input field a function for onChange and onBlur via props to let the TextField component know how to handle and where to write the value to the store? e.g.

```
<TextField
  name={`${this.state.movies}[${index}].name`}
  value={item.name}
  onBlur={(event) => console.log('onBlur action')}
  onChange={(event) => console.log('onChange action')}
/>
```

I have worked with modules such as 'redux-form', but it feels heavy, not that stable. I would like to control all by myself as the 'movies' form is just a collection without user side validations.

Answer (score 0):

Yup! Event propagation is the way to go. You definitely don't want to couple your `TextField` component with any redux or any other state management logic as it defeats the whole purpose of reusability. I would create handling functions in the Form component that would do that exact thing(e.g. `handleOnBlurMovieInput`, `handleOnChangeUserInput`) and pass those into the `TextField` as props respectively.

Comment: Thank you! So it would be a good approach to push down via props the handleOnBlur and handleOnChange functions from the parent component and call these functions via props inside the onChange and onBlur function in the TextField component to dispatch the value into the correct store state (defined in handleOnBlur/handleOnChange function in the parent component) ?